# Open link automatically after video has finished playing

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to have a html5 video automatically open another page after it has finished playing?

How could this be done in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [media events on MDN](http://jsfiddle.net/fJZYu/).

```
// Cross-browser attach event logic (might be useful for this one day)
function listen(evnt, elem, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) { // W3C DOM
        elem.addEventListener(evnt, func, false);
    }
    else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM
        var r = elem.attachEvent("on" + evnt, func);
        return r;
    }
    else alert('I\'m sorry, I\'m afraid I can\'t do that.');
}

// Attach to event
listen("ended", document.getElementById('myVideo'), DoSomething);

// Event handler
function DoSomething() {
    // Use window.open (new window), or window.location.href = '[your link]'
}​
```

Here's [a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/fJZYu/)

**EDIT**

Since you mentioned in a comment that you have jQuery, this will work as well:

```
$("#myVideo").on("ended", function() {
    // Use window.open (new window), or window.location.href = '[your link]'
});​
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p5hhJ/1/).

Comment: You can also create function inherit of Element.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but couldn't get this working in Chrome. It didn't work at jsfiddle for me either (no video loaded)...

Comment: @Sonypackman, I've tested this is Chrome and it's working fine. What version of Chrome are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can do it this way:

```
$("#myVideoElementID").bind("ended", function() {
  // Do stuff here
});
```

Comment: jQuery was not tagged. jQuery and JavaScript are not synonymous.

Comment: couldnt get this to work either (i have jquery).. Tried with a simple alert function but nothing happens..

Comment: Please check if you have any javascript errors, above code should be working fine.